How do I set up java-home variable correctly for Godot?
When exporting for android using Gradle build I get this error
I have no other java alternatives
I installed openjdk-17 through $ sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk openjdk-17-jre command
my Path is /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/gordey/.dotnet/tools:/home/gordey/.dotnet:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
This is my ~/.bashrc (not sure I set this up correctly)
I'm opening project through terminal using this command: $ godot4 /home/gordey/projects/godot-test -e
[There is no java.sh in my profile.d folder so I couldn't try this method text](https://i.sstatic.net/82YzUQUT.png)
I tried adding /bin to the end of JAVA_HOME but it changes nothing
I tried setting JAVA_HOME in .profile and open godot though the same terminal window and it didn't work too

did you do everything as per the documentation?

as for java, godot documentation only mentions openjdk-17 which, yes, I installed.
Is it possible that the command I used to install the jdk is incorrect?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You need to add the Java SDK path in Editor Settings -> Export -> Android:

After changing this, you will need to delete the /android/build folder from your project, and also the USER_HOME/.gradle folder on your system.
Then you can reinstall the build template via Project -> Install Android Build Template... and it will pick up the correct path.
